# disable access-control for unbound DNS server

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, unbound

I have a public DNS server that obviously needs to respond to everyone and anyone. Setting up the access-control directive allowing access from every IP results in a "netblock too large" error.

Does anyone know how I can disable access control for the unbound DNS server?

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: read the manual pages front to back. googled the problem. Nobody seems to run unbound servers for everyone, they're apparently just used for internal DNSs....

Answer (score 3):

I just set mine up with:

access-control: 0.0.0.0/0 allow

and it seems to allow anyone access.